# Multithreaded environment issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF control that is being handle, render and displayed in the main thread of my application. The control uploads thousands of data points into view in an object called "Layer." Here is a rough description of how the object/class hierarchy looks like:

```
public class WPFControl{

   private List<Layer> myLayers;

   public List<Layer> MyLayers{
      get{ return myLayer;}
   }       

   ...
}

public class Layer{
   private List<DataPoint> myDataPoints;

   public List<DataPoint> MyDataPoints{
        get{ return myDataPoints;}
   }

   ...
}

public class DataPoint{
   ....
}
```

Since the creation process of this "Layer" object takes some time because of the thousands of DataPoint it has to read and upload, I am creating that layer object in a different thread. That works great and returns the Layer object very nicely. The problem is when I try to do add it to the WPF control to be displayed like this:

```
myWpfControl.MyLayers.Add(layerCreatedInOtherThread);
```

the WPF control fires this error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
```

I thought, ok, I can then use the dispatcher like so:

```
myWpfControl.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)
 (()=>{                                   
    myWpfControl.MyLayers.Add(layerCreatedInOtherThread);
 })
 );
```

But I keep getting the same error. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: You can't do this. UI is not data. Get your data in a background thread, and data bind your UI instead of trying to manipulate it in procedural code.

Comment: `I am creating that layer object in a different thread.` Show the code.

Comment: Look at priority binding and background worker

Comment: Use the BackgroundWorker or TPL and a Task with a Synchronization Context

Comment: @Harrison why not make this a full-blown Answer instead of just a comment?

Comment: @philologon.  Ok, thanks.  Done.  I'm not as familiar with synchronization with TPL so I couldn't put that in my answer, if someone want to expand on it feel free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) you can run a task on another thread and then when it is completed have access to the results from the UI thread.

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

 //Start the work
 bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(null) //you can send an argument instead of null
```

Do the work

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, 
        DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Assign the result of the computation 
        // to the Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs 
        // object. This is will be available to the  
        // RunWorkerCompleted eventhandler.
        e.Result = CreateLayerInOtherThread(); //if you sent an arg instead of null it as availalbe in e.Argument and can be cast from object.
    }
```

Get the result once completed.  This runs on the UI thread so you can update it.

```
    private void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(
        object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown. 
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            // Next, handle the case where the user canceled  
            // the operation. 
            // Note that due to a race condition in  
            // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled 
            // flag may not have been set, even though 
            // CancelAsync was called.


        }
        else
        {
            // Finally, handle the case where the operation  
            // succeeded.
            Layer myLayer = (Layer)e.Result;
            myWpfControl.MyLayers.Add(myLayer);
        }


    }
```

Comment: This will not work because the background thread is creating `DispatcherObject`-derived objects, which of course are not associated to the "main" dispatcher.

Comment: @HighCore.  I'm not sure why this won't work, I don't understand your comment.  The intent of the BackgorundWorker is to run work on another thread and then have access to the Dispatcher when completed.  Do you suggest I delete this answer?  What do you suggest as a solution.

Comment: to make myself clear, the OP is probably creating `UI` elements in the background thread, there's no way that will work. He's mashing alltogether UI and data and therefore is forced to a single-threaded scenario. There's no way you can create UI elements in a background thread and expect them to work in another Thread's Dispatcher. My suggested solution is, as always, MVVM and DataBinding, as opposed to a winforms-like approach.

Comment: @HighCore I didn't realize this was a `UIElement`. It looks like from his code he is creating a layer and then feeding that to a property of a `UIElement`.  Did I get that wrong?  Is that still not possible?

Comment: @Harrison and at HighCore - I hope the original poster comes back and clarifies this uncertainty in his intent.  I want to know what the answer is myself since I plan to perform similar stuff some time in the future.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the discussion. @Harrison you are right, I am creating the layer in the second thread and feeding the result to a property of the WPF control (UIElement).

Comment: @LuisGarcia I think my solution will work for you, if you have any issues please let me know.